# How to use oslo.concurrency to synchronize access to a Python method?

Tags: python, concurrency, openstack

The [official documentation|https://docs.openstack.org/oslo.concurrency/latest/user/] makes it seem as is as:

```
from oslo_concurrency import lockutils
...

@lockutils.synchronized('myLock', external=True)
def my-function():
    pass
```

However, once i run my application, I get this error:

```
value required for option lock_path in group default
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set `external=True`, so that `lockutils` need a temporary directory to save info.
You could set `lock_path` globally with:

```
lockutils.set_defaults(lock_path='/home/user/tmp/')
```

Then `lockutils` should work.

For more information on how to use `oslo_concurrency.lockutils`, please go to this link: https://docs.openstack.org/oslo.concurrency/latest/reference/lockutils.html